# Highlight the background of my chart according to condition

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to highlight in background of my chart, when the market is flat.

Obviously, I am doing something wrong, since the background is "completely" green.

Would appreciate your expertise.

```
// --- Flatmarket START ---
// Calculate price range over a 10-bar period
price_range = high[20] - low[20]

// Set the threshold for flat market
threshold = 0.5 * price_range

// Check if the market is flat
flatMarket = (price_range <= threshold)
trendingMarket =  (price_range >= threshold)

// Check if the market is flat
bgcolor(flatMarket ? color.red : trendingMarket ? color.green : na)
```

It doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your math is off here.

`price_range = high[20] - low[20]` will always be a positive number because `high` is always greater than `low`. Say it is 10.

`threshold` will always be less than `price_range` because you do `threshold = 0.5 * price_range`. In our example `threshold` will be 5.

Therefore, `flatMarket` will always be `false` and `trendingMarket` will always be `true`.

```
flatMarket = (price_range <= threshold)  // 10 <= 5 -> false
trendingMarket =  (price_range >= threshold)  // 10 >= 5 -> true
```

This is why your background color is always green because `flatMarket` is always `false` and `trendingMarket` is always `true` in your `bgcolor()` call.

```
bgcolor(flatMarket ? color.red : trendingMarket ? color.green : na)
```

Comment: ha ha ha!, indeed really obvious and I haven't seen it, thanks anyway, I understand now.